# r pre-specify parts of file path

Tags: r

I currently have individual scripts for each species in my analysis, I'd like to try and get it into one script where I can specify at the beginning which species/year of data etc. I am analysing. 
I'd like to know if it is possible to instead set at the beginning of the script certain objects and then have more generic code to read in the files. for example;

existing code

```
ABR <- read.csv("Y:/Pelagic Work/FIN Data/2015/HOM/Abroad.csv",sep=",",skip = 2,header=T)
SCO <- read.csv("Y:/Pelagic Work/FIN Data/2015/HOM/Scotland.csv",sep=",",skip = 2,header=T)
```

I'd like something like;

```
Year <- 2015 
Species <- HOM

ABR <- read.csv("Y:/Pelagic Work/FIN Data/Year/Species/Abroad.csv",sep=",",skip = 2,header=T)
SCO <- read.csv("Y:/Pelagic Work/FIN Data/Year/Species/Scotland.csv",sep=",",skip = 2,header=T)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file.path` is the function for which you are looking

```
root <- "Y:/Pelagic Work/FIN Data"
year <- "2015"
species <- "HOM"

file <- "Abroad.csv"
ABR <- file.path(root, year, species, file)
```

From the docs "Faster than `paste(...)`" and works with the appropriate filepath separator for the system

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf` for this:

```
Year <- 2015
Species <- HOM

abroad.path <- sprintf("Y:/Pelagic Work/FIN Data/%s/%s/Abroad.csv", Year, Species)
scotland.path <- sprintf("Y:/Pelagic Work/FIN Data/%s/%s/Scotland.csv", Year, Species)

ABR <- read.csv(abroad.path, sep=",", skip=2, header=T)
SCO <- read.csv(scotland.path, sep=",", skip=2, header=T)
```

Answer (score 2):

I defined a helper function `getFileName()` which does the heavy lifting of building the path of the file you want to read.

```
getFileName <- function(root, year, species, file) {
    return (paste(root, year, species, file, sep="/"))
}

root <- "Y:/Pelagic Work/FIN Data"
year <- "2015"
species <- "HOM"
file <- "Abroad.csv"

fileName <- getFileName(root, year, species, file, sep="/")

ABR <- read.csv(fileName,sep=",",skip = 2,header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I was getting error - Error: unexpected '}' in "}" , so I added in () around return